# Can the default implementation of __repr__ be improved based on the __init__ function?

Tags: python

As per my understanding `__repr__` is used to represent a developer/interpreter friendly representation of the object and should possibly be a valid python code which when passed to `eval()` recreates an identical object.

From Python Docs:

> object.**repr**(self)
>
> Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines **repr**() but not **str**(), then **repr**() is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.

Link: [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

E.g:

```
class tie(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
t = tie('green')
repr(t) # prints <tie object at 0x10fdc4c10>

# can the default implementation be improved to tie(color='green')
# based on the parameters passed in the __init__ function
```

What challenges would be there to change that implementation apart from backward compatibility/ existing behavior?

Comment: I am not sure what is the question here... are you asking whether it is ok to change `__repr__` dunder method of the class? - it is, it serves a helpful role when debugging or reading logs / exception tracebacks, the statement with using `eval()` is not true, but it is helpful if object's repr has all the state information of an object - unless their state is huge and it would drown any other information of a log for example

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik I was a little confused, too... I think they're asking what's preventing the python developers from providing a different default implementation of `__repr__()` that's (for example) based on the signature of the class's `__init__()`.

Comment: the question is sort of why does python interpreter provide the default implementation as `<tie object at 0x10fdc4c10>` and not work a bit more to generate `tie(color='green')` which it can. Are there any caveats involved due to which generating a representation by looking at the parameters of `__init__` will be totally wrong?

Comment: @glibdud - exactly my point

Comment: oh ok, there are major problems with it- i will try to summarize some in an answer

Comment: Whats wrong with implement as `def __repr__(self): return "tie(color='{}')".format(self.color)`

Comment: the id(x) representation is useful in many cases, such as when you’re concerned about object identity or only type.  if not, it’s easy enough to modify.  not convinced a fancier system would be that useful for 90% of us.  you can also return str(self.__dict__) easily.

Comment: You could do something like `return "{0.__class__.__name__}({})".format(self, ", ".join('{}={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in self.__dict__.items())`. This would handle stuff like mutable objects, but it might have nothing to do with constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially what `pickle` is trying to do. The idea is that since an object in memory is a graph, if you revisit that graph you can reconstruct the object.

Pickle generates a series of instructions to reconstruct data, but, in principle, it could generate Python code directly.

While I'm going to consider all the problems with it, Pickling is used very heavily for distributed applications where systems need to transmit data from one process to another.

And `__repr__` methods are very handy in debugging when you want to be able to reconstruct an object by copying and pasting into a prompt.

Let's look at where pickling doesn't work:

1. Some objects actually represent objects! A network socket, for instance, identifies the kernel resources managing the actual network connection. Even if you could recreate those, there wouldn't be another machine listening.
2. Some objects have real world consequences. An object might represent a password or other secret that should not leave the process's memory e.g. by being printed to logs.
3. To determine which objects to construct first you must perform a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), and while fast algorithms exist, they aren't free. Especially, things can get hairy if another thread modifies the graph while this is happening.
4. If you save this data and try to reload it on another version, it will fail. If you design new versions to accept the old data, development slows to a crawl as your code becomes more contorted to deal with backwards compatibility.
5. It is very tightly coupled to your objects and Python's object model, so you wind up reimplementing it.
6. It has access to anything in Python, so if someone passes in `shutil.rmtree('/')` the machine will faithfully execute it.

Most of these aren't show stoppers, but to be fixed require tradeoffs. The main reason why the built-in `__repr__` does so little is to ensure that simple things stay simple.

And modules like [attrs](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/), which inspired the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module in python 3.7, provide a canned `__repr__` that largely does what you're asking for and answers most of the use cases that I think you're imagining.

I'm working on a language that adresses some of these issues, and I summarized [some of the different existing approaches](https://tenet-lang.org/contrast.html) to dealing with the issues I mention above.

Answer (score 4):

Having default repr based on how the object was created would bring inefficiencies and confusion

**Size**

the `__init__` arguments would have to be stored via copy somewhere in the object - making the object bloated

not all object simply copy those values into themselves

for example:

```
class GreedyMan:
    def __init__(self, coins):
        self.most_valuable_coin = max(coins)
```

you would have to save the whole coins collection here

**classes are mutable**

a Color class that is initialized with 0xff00ff can change over its lifespan into another color

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def dilute(self, factor):
        self.color = self.color * factor
```

the `dilute` can change the state of the class so you would no longer have a color of 0xff00ff but some other one and if something threw an exception like "I dont accept non red colors - provided Color('red')" the programmer would have some debugging to do until he notices someone used the `dilute` to get some wierd shade..

so why not print the whole state - all of the class properties

**result could be huge/infinite**

graphs can have nodes that contain other nodes and even cycles

```
class ChainPart:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

a=ChainPart(None)
b=ChainPart(a)
b.add_child(a)
```

the chain part `b` when printed out with all of its contents recursively would have to print `a` part which would print part `b` ... etc ad infinum

so the most obvious way to solve these issues is to leave repr simple and allow the programmer to change it with a custom `__repr__` method in the object class.

Comment: I sort of had a myopic view when I raised this question and my imagination of the __init__ was limited to that of say a plain object where the constructor would only be receiving the properties of the object as params and param names would be kept the same as the object property names. I am feeling like down-voting my own question now. >_<

Comment: objects like that exist - [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)  , their repr is the way you described as they are immutable and work only as containers - they do not change the parameters they were initialized with